# Can't connect to WiFi after spoofed MAC address

Tags: wi-fi, mac-address

I'm changing the MAC address on my Android device; however, once I change it I get disconnected from the WiFi network that I'm connected to and then I'm unable to reconnect to the WiFi.

I realized that I can connect to unsecure WiFi but not secure. I know the MAC address is changing properly because I did packet capturing with WireShark and the spoofed MAC shows as the MAC address of the packets.

I have tried forgetting and reconnecting to the secure WiFi network, but it still doesn't connect. When I changed back the MAC to the original value, it works fine. I can only connect with the real MAC address, but not the spoofed one.

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure MAC filtering is disabled on your router or your spoofed address is allowed to connect to the network and try again.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps the router is smarter than you thought or the Mac address isn't spoofed properly....you need to format your Android phone to be able to reconnect to other WiFi

Comment: That seems pretty extreme... can you explain and justify that as to exactly why this is the correct answer?