# IP configuration failure / Check password and try again on wi-fi networks after changing mac address

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, mac-address, redmi-note-4

<sup>Device in question Redmi Note 4, Android 9.0, Xiaomi EU ROM, rooted with lsposed</sup>

I enabled MAC randomisation feature in developer options, and yes the mac appears to have changed but I can longer connect to wi-fi networks. Open networks return "IP configuration error" while encrypted networks give "Check password and try again". I tried mac changing xposed based apps and these don't give any better results.

<sup>Related question: [Can't connect to WiFi after spoofed MAC address](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/116044/209414) (slightly different still no solution)</sup>

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What errors do you see in `logcat -b all` when "IP configuration error" comes?

Comment: Let me me check that I will get back to you...

Comment: I ended up editing the `WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini file` and this time it did not give that error